# SOAP API returns wrong address

Tags: soap, nginx

I use nginx with php5-fpm and I have problem with SOAP webservice. Magento returns wrong address in wsdl.

```
<service name="MagentoService">
  <port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://aaa.local/index.php/?type=soap"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

Should be something like that

```
<service name="MagentoService">
  <port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://aaa.local/api/soap"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

My vhost nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name aaa.local;
    root   /var/www/aaa;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
           expires 30d;
        }

    location /api {
        rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
        rewrite ^/api/soap /api.php?type=soap last;
    }


    location /app/                { deny all; }
    location /includes/           { deny all; }
    location /lib/                { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location /var/                { deny all; }
    location /var/reports                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/aaa$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE aaa;
        }
}
```

Anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: So the solution was simple.... I have to use proper link for webservice https://aaa.local/index.php/api/soap?wsdl

Comment: You can add you answer, then accept your answer and this question will no longer show up without an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution was simple.... I have to use proper link for webservice

`http://aaa.local/index.php/api/soap?wsdl`

instead of

`http://aaa.local/api/soap`